# Match all occurence of a patther with Start string and end string regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string and I want to find all the occurrence of the pattern:

```
some random content 1...
.
.
..

[list start]
some random content 2 ..
.
.
..
[list end]

some random content 3 ..
.
.
..

[list start]
some random content 4 ..
.
.
..
[list end]

some random content 5
.
.
..
```

So I want to capture all the content that is appearing between [list start] and [list end] i.e "some random content 2" and "some random content 4"

I used the regex `/[list start]([\s\S]*)[list end]/g` which ofc captures everything from the first [list start] to the last [list end] i.e "some random content 2 , 3 , 4"

How can I write the right regex to get all occurrence of this pattern in Javascript?

Comment: Try this one: `/\[list start\]([\s\S]*?)\[list end\]/g`

Comment: over zealous ppl downvoting my question while I was still editing it (right after I posted it when I realised that everything inside tags disappeared ) is just wrong. Do these ppl realize that ppl asking a question on StackOverflow are not plain stupid and if they find a question incomplete it might be a result of something other the question being stupid or irrelevant for SF(which their downvoting implies)? Shouldn't Stackoverflow stop downvoting or upvoting while a person is editing a question?

Comment: Thanks! your regex totally worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var str = `
some random content 1...
.
.
..

[list start]
some random content 2 ..
.
.
..
[list end]

some random content 3 ..
.
.
..

[list start]
some random content 4 ..
.
.
..
[list end]

some random content 5
.
.
..`;
var res = str.match(/\[list start\]([\s\S]*?)\[list end\]/g);
console.log(res);
```